# Why is the carbon dioxide we exhale transparent?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, phase

Why is carbon dioxide that comes from dry ice opaque and smoky while the carbon dioxide that we exhale transparent?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Essentially, because the carbon dioxide sublimates from solid (dry ice) to gas at a very low temperature (roughly −78 °C at 1 atm), it causes water vapour in the air to condense, causing a visible fog. Thus what you are seeing is *not* carbon dioxide, but rather water.

When we exhale and it is reasonably warm, the carbon dioxide expelled is roughly body temperature (36–37.5 °C) and so we do not see any fog forming.

What happens when we exhale in cold weather is a bit different. Our breath contains a high percentage of water, higher than the percentage of water that can stay in gaseous form at a low temperature. Thus the ‘extra’ water condenses into droplets.

For reference, here is the phase diagram of $\ce{CO2}$:

[image: Phase Diagram of carbon dioxide]

And here is the phase diagram of $\ce{H2O}$:

[image: Phase Diagram of H2O]

And here is the saturation fraction of water at various temperatures at 1 atm (sea level):

[image: Saturation fraction of H2O by temperature (dew point)]

Comment: How does *saturation fraction* relate to *saturation vapour pressure*?

Comment: @gerrit saturation fraction is the concentration while vapour pressure is a pressure. They're related by the formula $p=nRT/V$ where p is pressure, n is amount of the gas in mol, V is volume, T is temperature and R is the gas constant.